# Find a real root of: $p(x) = x^4-8x^3+25x^2-36x+20$

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have to find a root of this polynomial: $p(x) = x^4-8x^3+25x^2-36x+20$

The possible roots are: $\{\pm1\pm2\pm4\pm5\pm10\pm20\}$

Is there any other way to easily check which of these values ​​are roots of $p (x)$?

Comment: Try graphing $p(x)$ and see what you get.

Comment: this is the set of candidates for a rational root try x=2

Comment: I would look at a translate, $q(x) = p(x+2)$   which ought to have no cubic term

Comment: You just need to check the positive values. Negative ones would give you positive results...

Comment: By inspection(plugging in the possible rational roots), you get that $x=2$ is a root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting question here is whether there are "easy" alternatives to simply evaluating $p(x)$ explicitly for the twelve values listed, from $\pm1$ to $\pm20$ -- that is, how much arithmetic can we avoid doing? (We'll set aside the question of whether it's worth trying to avoid simply doing a bunch of straightforward arithmetic.)

As PAM1499 pointed out in comments, $x^4-8x^3+25x^2-36x+20$ becomes a sum of positive numbers when $x$ is negative, so that cuts the list in half right there.

Here are some arguments that rule out $x=4,5,10,20$ without doing much in the way of arithmetic.

Grouping terms as $(x-8)x^3+(25x-36)x+20$ makes it easy to rule out $x=10$ and $20$ for much the same reason: each of the three groups is clearly positive in those two cases.

For $x=5$, we have $25\mid(x^4-8x^3+25x^2)$ but $-36\cdot5+20=-160$ and $25\not\mid160$, so we cannot have $p(5)=0$.

For $x=4$, we have $16\mid(x^4-8x^3+25x^2-36x)$ but $16\not\mid20$, so $p(4)\not=0$.

It's easy enough to calculate $p(1)=1-8+25-36+20=46-44=2\not=0$. You can avoid even that much calculation, though, by looking at things mod $4$: $x^4-8x^3+25x^2-36x+20\equiv x^4+x^2$ mod $4$, so $p(1)\equiv1+1\not\equiv0$ mod $4$.

This leaves, of course, $x=2$, which turns out to be a (double!) root.  I can't think of any easy way to verify that without doing at least some arithmetic.

Remark: Will Jagy's inspired answer gets quite quickly to the complete solution. Note, however, that all the arithmetic of verifying the identity has been omitted.

Comment: Barry. I did think of putting in a comment to the effect that finding the "depressed" is a standard task for dealing with roots of a cubic or quartic. A bonus, I do not know the details, is Michael Rozenberg's claim that a depressed quartic is a (difference, I think ) of two squares(possibly with some real coefficients, not sure), which "works out well" under contest type conditions.  I know how it goes when the linear coefficient is also zero.

Answer (score 6):

$$   p(x+2) = x^4 + x^2  $$

................................